# Copiar archivos nuevos

Tags: batch, .bat

Tengo dificultades a la hora de copiar archivos nuevos o modificados de una carpeta a otra.

El código que tengo es este:

```
xcopy "C:\XXXX\*.xml" "C:\X"  /d /Y
```

El código funciona bien, la cosa es que en la carpeta X, cada cierto tiempo se borran los archivos, entonces el código del *xcopy* me vuelve a copiar todos y solo necesitaría los nuevos que van entrando cada X tiempo o los que se han modificado.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que podrías usar el parámetro `/M` que sólo copiará los ficheros que estén marcados para copiar y una vez copiado lo desmarca como pendiente de copiar. Quedaría así

```
xcopy "C:\XXXX*.xml" "C:\X" /d /Y /M
```

Esto sólo copiaría los ficheros cuya fecha sea posterior a la del destino, como ya tenías, pero también si no ha sido copiado previamente (aunque esté borrado en el destino).

Ten en cuenta que sólo funcionaría si los ficheros originales no son manipulados por otra aplicación que cambie el atributo de archivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido.